# What are the downsides of always using numpy arrays instead of python lists?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm writing a program in which I want to flatten an array, so I used the following code:

```
list_of_lists = [["a","b","c"], ["d","e","f"], ["g","h","i"]]
flattened_list = [i for j in list_of_lists for i in j]
```

This results in `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']`, the desired output.

I then found out that using a `numpy` array, I could've done the same simply by using `np.array(((1,2),(3,4),(5,6))).flatten()`.

I was wondering if there is any downside to always using `numpy` arrays in the place of regular Python lists? In other words, is there something that Python lists can do which numpy arrays can't?

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question.  They are both useful.  `numpy` is best for  calculations, lists are better for iteration.  Also distinguish between numeric arrays, string dtypes arrays, and object dtype arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj but since `numpy` arrays can also be iterated upon, is there any downside to always using them (in the place of python lists)?

Comment: @Bobotheclown yes they are much less efficient for non-primitive dtypes, i.e. for anything you would use `object` dtype for.

Comment: Iteration on numpy arrays is slower.  Your example uses strings.  `numpy` doesn't have 'native' string methods.  Its np.char` functions apply Python string methods to each element.

Comment: When you create that array you use a tuple of tuples.  Lists and tuples are integral to python, even when using numpy.

Answer (score 1):

With your small example, the list comprehension is faster than the array method, even when taking the array creation out of the timing loop:

```
In [204]: list_of_lists = [["a","b","c"], ["d","e","f"], ["g","h","i"]] 
     ...: flattened_list = [i for j in list_of_lists for i in j]    

In [205]: timeit [i for j in list_of_lists for i in j]                                                       
757 ns ± 17.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [206]: np.ravel(list_of_lists)                                                                            
Out[206]: array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'], dtype='<U1')

In [207]: timeit np.ravel(list_of_lists)                                                                     
8.05 µs ± 12.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [208]: %%timeit x = np.array(list_of_lists) 
     ...: np.ravel(x)                                                                                                     
2.33 µs ± 22.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

With a much larger example, I expect [208] to get better.

If the sublists differ in size, the array is not 2d, and flatten does nothing:

```
In [209]: list_of_lists = [["a","b","c",23], ["d",None,"f"], ["g","h","i"]] 
     ...: flattened_list = [i for j in list_of_lists for i in j]                                             
In [210]: flattened_list                                                                                     
Out[210]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 23, 'd', None, 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
In [211]: np.array(list_of_lists)                                                                            
Out[211]: 
array([list(['a', 'b', 'c', 23]), list(['d', None, 'f']),
       list(['g', 'h', 'i'])], dtype=object)
```

Growing lists is more efficient:

```
In [217]: alist = []                                                                                         
In [218]: for row in list_of_lists: 
     ...:     alist.append(row) 
     ...:                                                                                                    
In [219]: alist                                                                                              
Out[219]: [['a', 'b', 23], ['d', None, 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
In [220]: np.array(alist)                                                                                    
Out[220]: 
array([['a', 'b', 23],
       ['d', None, 'f'],
       ['g', 'h', 'i']], dtype=object)
```

We strongly discourage iterative concatenation.  Collect the sublists or arrays in a list first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are.  The rule of thumb would be to remember `numpy.array` is better for  data of the same datatype (all integers, all double precision fp, all booleans, strings of the same length etc) instead of a mix bag of things.  In the latter case you might just as well using generic list, considering this:

```
In [93]: a = [b'5', 5, '55', 'ab', 'cde', 'ef', 4, 6]

In [94]: b = np.array(a)

In [95]: %timeit 5 in a
65.6 ns ± 0.79 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [96]: %timeit 6 in a  # worst case
219 ns ± 5.48 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [97]: %timeit 5 in b
10.9 µs ± 217 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

look at this several magnitudes of performance difference, where `numpy.array` is slower! Certainly this depends on the dimension of the list, and in this particular case depends on the index of 5 or 6 (worst case of O(n) complexity), but you get the idea.

Comment: The mix of data-types isn't the problem, the problem is `dtype=object`, although, heterogenous `numpy.ndarray` have to be `dtype=object`

Answer (score -1):

Numpy arrays and functions are better for the most part. Here is an article if you want to look into it more: https://webcourses.ucf.edu/courses/1249560/pages/python-lists-vs-numpy-arrays-what-is-the-difference