# Difference between % and %% in ipython magic commands

Tags: ipython, ipython-magic

What difference does it make to use `%timeit` and `%%timeit` in ipython? Because when I read the documentation using `?%timeit` and `?%%timeit` it was the same documentation. So, what difference does adding `%` as prefix make?

Comment: `%magic` is a line magic, which uses input on the same line.  `%%magic` is a cell magic, which takes multiline input.  I use `%timeit` to test a simple expression.  I use `%%timeit to do setup on the first line, and the following lines to a multiline expression.

Comment: Any examples and documentation avaliable @hpaulj

Comment: I've used them a lot in my numpy answers

Comment: e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58515904/901925, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58228285/901925, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57899108/901925

Comment: It would be useful to have a more general question about the difference between `%` and `%%` in ipython, that doesnt' focus just on `timeit`, and a good answer that explains the difference between line magic and cell magic. If you google it the results are awful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, one percentage sign is referred to as *line magic* and applies just to code that follows it on that same line. Two percentage signs is referred to as *cell magic* and applies to everything that follows in that entire cell.

As nicely put in [The Data Science Handbook](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.03-magic-commands.html):

> Magic commands come in two flavors: line magics, which are denoted by
> a single % prefix and operate on a single line of input, and cell
> magics, which are denoted by a double %% prefix and operate on
> multiple lines of input.

Some magic commands, like `timeit`, can work as line magic or cell magic:

Used as line magic:

```
%timeit y = 2 if x < 3 else 4
```

Used as cell magic:

```
%%timeit
if x < 3:
    y=2
else:
    y=4
```